# How to convert seeds into private key?

Tags: flutter, dart, private-key, ethers.js, web3dart

how to **convert bip39 mnemonic seed phrase into private key** without any libraries like *web3* or *ethers.js*
basically I'm trying to replicate my metamasks wallets private key

so I would like to write a function that takes my seed words as my input and return the private key for ethereum based wallets

```dart
privateKey = function([seed_1, seed_2, ..., seed_12]);
```

Where do I get started?

Answer (score 0):

@elangovan you can use dart's [BIP32](https://pub.dev/packages/bip32) implementation and follow below steps

1. Convert Mnemonic(12 words) to seed using `bip32.mnemonicToSeed`
2. Seedto HD Master Node using `bip32.BIP32.fromSeed`
3. Derive child node at desired HD path`(m/44'/0')`

However, you can derive public and private keys from the child node.